# REST : suggestions on collecting firmware version details from Softaleyr API

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure, bare-metal-server

Is there any way to collect firmware version from all the bare metal servers using `slcli` command line or using any other API method ?

I have already gone through the following links

https://softlayer.github.io/reference/softlayerapi/

https://softlayer.github.io/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Hardware_Component_Firmware/

But it wasn't of much help to me, as I'm new to API scripting.

Comment: In what way were they unhelpful?  What parts of those documents didn't help?  What concrete methods have you tried?  What have you tried in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SLCLI allows only to update the firmware, but you should be able to use rest, soap, xmlrpc, python, ruby, java, go, etc., or any other supported language to retrieve this data through [object-masks](https://softlayer.github.io/article/object-masks/).

Try with the following REST call, it should retrieve the firmware information for a bare metal server:

```
https://[unserName]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/[baremetalID]/getObject?objectMask=mask[components[hardwareComponentModel[firmwares],revision.firmware]]
```

Change [unserName], [apiKey], and [baremetalID] with your own information.

For all hardware devices into the account:

```
https://[userName]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getHardware?objectMask=mask[id,fullyQualifiedDomainName,components[hardwareComponentModel[firmwares],revision.firmware]]
```

https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/getObject
https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/getComponents
https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getHardware
https://softlayer.github.io/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Hardware/#components
https://softlayer.github.io/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/#components
https://softlayer.github.io/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Hardware_Component/

Comment: Thank you , this was really helpful for me. If you could edit out "objectMask=maskmask..." as "object=mask..."  , it'd be great. i got an error for that.